# Move files up one directory

Tags: linux, files, move

How can I move the entire folder up one level in the directory structure ? Using rsync or mv does not quite work.

```
rsync /var/www/html/wordpress/ /var/www/html/
skipping directory .

mv /var/www/html/wordpress/ /var/www/html/
mv: '/var/www/html/wordpress/' and '/var/www/html/wordpress' are the same file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a wildcard and remove the directory afterwards:

```
mv /var/www/html/wordpress/* /var/www/html/ && rm -r /var/www/html/wordpress
```

Answer (score 0):

To "move the entire folder up one level in the directory structure ", as asked, it's needed to address the source and destination.

From:  /var/www/html/wordpress/

To: /var/www/wordpress/

you would need

```
$ mv /var/www/html/wordpress/ /var/www/wordpress/
```

Be mindful of a couple of edge cases, like if:

1. the directory /var/www/wordpress already exist before you try moving  /var/www/html/wordpress up one level; or
2. files (-) and directories (d) vs other types like links, sockets, block devices, etc. How they behave in another path, for example.